# CentOS login GUI Issue

Tags: centos6, graphical-user-interface, gtk

I have trapped in weird problem. My Setup is CentOS 6.3 64 Bit

My login screen is blinking so frequently that I am unable to see and login into it. The issue is I have installed gtk2 using yum install gtk2 after this the problem starts!

can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not really on-topic here on Server Fault, but <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> should bring you to a text console where you can try if removing the those packages restores the display.

On a side note: The fact that you're still on CentOS 6.3 implies that you don't regularly patch and you have may accidently installed packages that do require a more up to date system.